# VBA slow process for removing rows based on condition

Tags: vba, excel, row

I have a VBA Excel code with that checks values in a specific column. If the row in that column contains the value 'Delete' and then deletes the row.

The code works well, but it is really slow. Any ideas on how to get the code run faster?

```
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim i As Integer, counter As Integer
    'Set the range to evaluate to rng.
    Set rng1 = Range("g1:g1000")
    'initialize i to 1
    i = 1
    'Loop for a count of 1 to the number of rows
    'in the range that you want to evaluate.
    For counter = 1 To rng1.Rows.Count
        'If cell i in the range1 contains an "Delete"
        'delete the row.
        'Else increment i
        If rng1.Cells(i) = "Delete" Then
            rng1.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
```

Thanks

c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub deletingroutine()
  Dim r As Range
  For Each r In Range("g1:g1000")
     If r = "delete" Then r.EntireRow.Delete

  Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, but there is a problem with the code. If there are two subsequent entries with the value 'delete' only the first one is deteted. I think I tried something similar. Maybe is due to the version of Excel. I'm using Office 2010

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution with the Autofilter function.

Hope it helps someone

```
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UploadSummary")
    lastRow = ws.Range("G" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = ws.Range("G1:G" & lastRow)
    ' filter and delete all but header row
    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="delete" ' 7 refers to the 7th column
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting the rows (on collumn G) then deleting all marked ("delete") rows in one action. That is much faster.